# AngularJS two-way data binding not working properly in directive

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

i am trying to implement radio-button list using ng-repeat.
**typeList.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="type in types" >
    <input type="radio" id={{type.id}} name="{{type.name}}"  ng-model="result" ng-value="type.id" >
    {{type.name}}
    <div> Result {{result}} </div> //result is changing only in the row of clicked radio-button. It should change in every row.(two way data-binding).
</div>
```

**Directive:**

```
angular.module('app').directive('myList',function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                types: '=',   //here list is passed to be printed with ng-repeat
                result: '='   //here I want to store which radio-button was selected last time by id
            },
            templateUrl: 'html/typeList.html'
        };


    });
```

Directive has isolated scope. I am passing two parameters. List to be printed with radio buttons and result object which stores answer(id-what radio button was clicked last time) in parent scope. Unfortunately whenever i click on radio-buttons my result is changing only locally.

```
 Passing parameters to my directive.
 <div my-list types="list" result="selected"></div>



  Passed list and result paramater from controller to myList directive.

 $scope.list   = [
        { id: 1, name:'Name 1' },
        { id: 2, name:'Name 2' },
        { id: 3, name:'Name 3' }
    ];

$scope.selected = -1;
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you show how are you adding your directive to the html code?

Comment: sure, i updated it.

Comment: What does `list` contain?

Comment: i put list content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a non-primitive object to the model to get its reference for two-war binding. Just wrap `selected` into an object for its reference.

In your controller use.

```
$scope.list = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Name 2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Name 3'
  }];
  $scope.ctrlModel = {
    selected: -1
  }
```

And in the Markup that is `'html/typeList.html'`

```
<div ng-repeat="type in types" >
  <input type="radio" id={{type.id}} ng-model="result.selected" ng-value="type.id" >
     {{type.name}}
</div>
Result {{result.selected}}
```

Working [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/6nrqeL56/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try to have scope variables as object like

`$scope.types = {
    list: {},
    selected: 'radioValueThatNeedsToBeSelected'
}`